# Why does the getPaths method of Swagger Parser not return all paths?

Tags: java, swagger

I have a Swagger 1.2 doc.json and the following Java code which uses Swagger Parser to extract all the paths from this document. The problem is that the parser does not get all the paths (from 50 it shows me only 27).

```java
public class Temps {

    public static void main (String[]args ) {
        int totale=0;
        Swagger swagger = new SwaggerParser().read("C:\\Users\\eya\\Desktop\\nodes.json");
         Map<String, Path> paths = swagger.getPaths(); 
         for (Map.Entry<String, Path> p : paths.entrySet()) {
                Path path = p.getValue();
                totale ++;
                Map<HttpMethod, Operation> operations = path.getOperationMap();
                for (java.util.Map.Entry<HttpMethod, Operation> o : operations.entrySet()) {
                    System.out.println("===");
                    System.out.println("PATH:" + p.getKey());
                    System.out.println("Http method:" + o.getKey());
                    System.out.println("Summary:" + o.getValue().getSummary());
                    System.out.println("Parameters number: " + o.getValue().getParameters().size());
                    for (Parameter parameter : o.getValue().getParameters()) {
                        System.out.println(" - " + parameter.getName());
                    }
                    System.out.println("Responses:");
                    for (Map.Entry<String, Response> r : o.getValue().getResponses().entrySet()) {
                        System.out.println(" - " + r.getKey() + ": " + r.getValue().getDescription());
                    }

                }
         }
         System.out.println(totale);
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what causes this problem?

Comment: Is it possible that you're confusing _paths_ with _operations_? A single path (e.g. `/something`) can have multiple operations - `GET /something`, `POST /something`, `DELETE /something` etc. So you may have 27 paths but 50 operations.

Comment: If this ^^ is not the case, can you post your `nodes.json` file or a link to it - so that others can reproduce the issue?

Comment: @Helen [link](https://developer.opentext.com/awd/resources/apis/cs-rest-api-for-cs-16-s/nodes.json)  I need to get all the methods and its paths !

Comment: @Helen i have over 50 paths in this doc but the java code shows only 27 :'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are duplicate paths in your API definition, for example:

```
"path": "api/v2/nodes/{id}",
"description": "Get a node",
...
"path": "api/v2/nodes/{id}",
"description": "Get a virtual folder",
```

```
"path": "api/v2/nodes/actions",
"description": "Get actions for the selected node IDs",
...
"path": "api/v2/nodes/actions",
"description": "Get actions for the selected node IDs",
```

Duplicate paths [are not allowed](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/1.2.md#522-api-object) by the Swagger 1.2 Specification:

> In the `apis` array, there MUST be only one API Object per `path`.

The parser simply ignores the duplicates.

Comment: So plz do you have any solution :( ??

Comment: Use a JSON parser instead of Swagger parser. A generic JSON parser won't care about Swagger format specifics/limitations.

Comment: th JSON Parser does not work neither :'( can you help me please !!

Comment: Please [ask a new question](/questions/ask), post the new code and specify which JSON parser you used.

Comment: Here is the [link of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60916753/swagger-parser-does-not-get-all-the-paths-from-swagger-json) and I'm so greatful for your responding