# Swagger Parser does not get all the paths from swagger.json

Tags: java, json, swagger, jsonparser

Duplicate paths are [not allowed](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/1.2.md#522-api-object) by the Swagger 1.2 Specification:

> In the apis array, there MUST be only one API Object per path.

The parser simply ignores the duplicates. and I have a [swagger.json file](https://developer.opentext.com/awd/resources/apis/cs-rest-api-for-cs-16-s/nodes.json) and I want to extract all the paths and their methods from this file. I tried to use Json Parser but I have no idea how to use it. How can I do so?
Here is my code :

```
   import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

import io.swagger.models.HttpMethod;
import io.swagger.models.Operation;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Iterator;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class JSONReadExample {
    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "deprecation" })
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        try {
            Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\eya\\Desktop\\nodes.json"));
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
            JSONArray apis = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("apis");
            Iterator<JSONObject> iterator = apis.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(iterator.next());


            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

and it shows me only the whole path ! I don't know to extract the opération and the description ...

Comment: *"I tried to use Json Parser"* - Which exactly JSON parser did you try (package, classname)? Can you post the code you've tried with that parser that didn't work for you? (Assuming the code is different from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60903944).)

Comment: @Helen here is the thing : when I use Swagger Parser for a big json file it does not work ! because when I've reduced the nomber of lines it worked but it shows some paths then I've reduced it more and it showed me all the paths ! So I guess it's a bug or an error from the swagger Parser

Comment: @Helen try to copy the json file (nodes.json) to a local folder then try to run my code ! it shows nothing !!!! then try to reduce it ! for exemple try to delete the "model" part from that file and re-run the code it will show u only 27 path then reduce the number of paths to 20 it will show u the 20 paths

Comment: @Helen you can see the changes ! I edited the post